# write newline to file in TeX/LaTeX

Tags: text, latex

I have a latex document that I want to use to write text to a plain text file.  I want macros to be expanded, so I can't use `\filecontents` (which just saves input verbatim to a file)

So far I have

```
\newwrite\metadatafile
\immediate\openout\metadatafile=\jobname-meta.txt
\immediate\write\metadatafile{Title: \jobname\string

Tags: \coursecode.\secnum.\termcode, \coursecode.\termcode, ...

Description:
...}
\immediate\closeout\metadatafile
```

What comes out in the text file inserts `\par` tokens instead of my double-newlines, and doesn't have any newlines in it at all.  How can I get newlines and have a regular plain text file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two answers:  One is to just use a lot of `\write` statements, one for each line you want written.  That is, `\write` writes a *line* to the file, including the newline character.  So a blank line can be done with just

```
\write\metadatafile{}
```

Or you can use the primitive `\newlinechar`.  In plain tex the double-carat macro `^^J` is aliased to `\newlinechar` so you can use that as well.  See pages 228 and 348 of *The TeXBook*.

While I have that book open, I looked up the importance of the `\immediate` primitive before `\write`.  All usages of `\write` cited also use `\immediate`.  I've tried without the `\immediate` and without it things don't get written.